# Submission status changed to "submitted" after "awaiting reviewer scores"

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, paper-submission

I submitted my article to a SAGE journal roughly six weeks ago. The status of the submission was "awaiting reviewer scores" for four weeks and few days ago it changed to "submitted". Any idea what this means? Does it mean that the article is with the editor who goes through the reviewer comments? Or does it mean that the article has been sent for new reviewers?

I have also checked the typical workflow of the journal, but was not able to find similar situation.

Comment: Maybe reviews are late or reviewers have dropped out, and they need new ones. That's at least a possibility, but these status messages are often all over the place, and I recommend to only worry about them if you have nothing better to do.

Comment: It could be meaningless.

Comment: While this question is not *quite* a duplicate, I think it is more helpful to close it as a duplicate instead of closing it as "depending on individual circumstances."